# Problems with a median value function C++

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to create a problem in zybooks (C++) that find the median value of a vector. Here is the function I wrote to do so:

```
double FindMedianScore(vector<int>& scores)
{
   sort(scores.begin(), scores.end());
   int median_score;
   if ((scores.size() % 2) == 0)
   {
      median_score = (scores.at((scores.size() / 2) - 1) + 
scores.at(scores.size() / 2)) / 2;   
   }
   else if ((scores.size() % 2) != 0)
   {
      median_score = scores.at(scores.size() / 2);
   }
   return median_score;    
}
```

In all the tests it passes, except for the random values test. zybooks gives the function a vector of 250 random values and wants the median. As far as I can tell there is nothing wrong with my code, but I fail the test no matter what I change. Any thoughts?

Comment: If `scores.size()` is 0 then exception is thrown.

Comment: median_score is an int. What if the 2 median values in the vector add up to an odd number? It's gonna be rounded down and not keep the decimal

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with this code. Some of them have been pointed out in the comments already.

The biggest one was identified with donpsabance: your `median_score` variable is declared as an `int`, even though you're returning a `double`. The calculation that averages the two medians:

> ```
> median_score = (scores.at((scores.size() / 2) - 1) + scores.at(scores.size() / 2)) / 2;
> ```

is done using integer arithmetic, so if there is a remainder in the division, it won't be reflected in the value that you return.

S.M. identified another possible issue, depending on how the validation tests are constructed: your code assumes that the input vector has a non-zero length. If that's guaranteed, then you are fine. If not, then your code will throw an exception.

That should address the *correctness* issues, but your code can still be improved in a couple of more ways.

The first thing I don't like is the `else if` clause:

> ```
> else if ((scores.size() % 2) != 0)
> ```

You don't need the conditional `if` there, since that's the only condition that could possibly be true once execution has arrived at the `else`. Just use an `else`.

Second, if you add an explicit check for a zero-length input vector, you can index directly into the vector instead of needing to call `at`. Aside from performance, the explicit check is a good idea anyway, since it allows you to throw a more appropriate exception.

Slightly rewritten, your code could look something like:

```
double FindMedianScore(vector<int>& scores)
{
    // Ensure input vector contains at least one element.
    const auto length = scores.size();
    if (length == 0)
    {
        throw std::domain_error("'scores' vector is empty.");
    }

    // Sort the elements of the vector in place.
    std::sort(std::begin(scores), std::end(scores));

    // Determine the median.
    double median_score;
    if ((length % 2) == 0)
    {
       median_score = static_cast<double>(scores[(length / 2) - 1] + scores[length / 2]) / 2.0;
    }
    else
    {
        median_score = scores[length / 2];
    }
    return median_score;  
}
```

Or even:

```
double FindMedianScore(vector<int>& scores)
{
    // Ensure input vector contains at least one element.
    const auto length = scores.size();
    if (length == 0)
    {
        throw std::domain_error("'scores' vector is empty.");
    }

    // Sort the elements of the vector in place.
    std::sort(std::begin(scores), std::end(scores));

    // Determine the median.
    double median_score = scores[length / 2];
    if ((length % 2) == 0)
    {
       median_score += scores[(length / 2) - 1];
       median_score /= 2.0;
    }
    return median_score;  
}
```

But, if you think a bit harder, you'll see that there is an even better way. Here, we are sorting the entire vector, which is an O(n log n) operation. But you don't actually need to sort the entire vector to determine the median. As it turns out, the C++ standard library has the perfect algorithm to do what you need: [`std::nth_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element). This does only a *partial* sort, and has a running time of O(n).

```
double FindMedianScore(vector<int>& scores)
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::next;
    using std::end;

    // Ensure input vector contains at least one element.
    const auto length = scores.size();
    if (length == 0)
    {
        throw std::domain_error("'scores' vector is empty.");
    }

    const auto halfLength = (length / 2);

    // Do an in-place partial sort on the vector, rearranging elements such that
    // the middle element is as if the vector were fully sorted.
    std::nth_element(begin(scores), next(begin(scores), halfLength), end(scores);

    // Determine the median.
    // If the container's length is odd, the median element is the one exactly in
    // the middle. Otherwise, if the container's length is even, the median is the
    // mean of the two median values. Since std::nth_element guarantees that all
    // preceding elements are less-than or equal to the target, and all subsequent
    // elements are greater-than or equal to the target, we can retrieve the
    // other median value by just calling std::max_element. This is more efficient
    // than doing another partial sort with std::nth_element.
    double median_score = scores[halfLength];
    if ((length % 2) == 0)
    {
       median_score += *std::max_element(begin(scores), next(begin(elements), halfLength));
       median_score /= 2.0;
    }
    return median_score;  
}
```